# Python how identify if an instance has been changed without making a copy?

Tags: python, hash

I'm trying to write a function to determine if an object has been modified at one point during the execution of the program.

I don't want to duplicate the object because this will take a lot of memory.

My object is a dataclass and has a few lists of dataclasses that might have nested dataclasses within them, but at the bottom level you'll only find primitive variables (str, ints, bool, ...)

Since these objects need to be modifiable I can't use `frozen=True`. What I've come up so far is `hash(str(self)) == PreviousHash` but this starts slowing down greatly as the amount of data increases.

What would you do to be able get a "hash" of a dataclass instance like this without having to do a slow convertion to a string first?

Comment: Is it feasible to define your dataclasses so that the only way to modify them "correctly" is to use properties whose setters can mark an object as dirty?

Comment: Thank you for the alternative. Not perfect (the object will still be dirty if changed and then set back to the original vale) but I like it better than what I have now

Comment: Hm. Each setter could track its own original value (or at least, value at the last "checkpoint") to determine if a change dirties or "cleans" an object. The code gets complicated fast :)

Comment: Agreed and keeping the original value stored almost doubles the space needed to store the object. A simple `dirty = True` should solve most issues and I don't mind the rare instance where I process an instance that hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a foolproof solution, but you could use a Proxy class to wrap your dataclasses recursively and set a flag whenever anything is modified. It'll impact performance somewhat by adding indirections and dynamic behavior, but at least it won't get worse as the dataclasses get larger.

Here's a first draft at it.

```
class Proxy:
    """
    Wraps an object to keep track of modifications, including to its children.
    """
    def __init__(self, obj, modified_flag=None):
        # Must use `super().__setattr__` to avoid recursing on itself.
        super().__setattr__('_obj', obj)
        super().__setattr__('_modified_flag', modified_flag or [False])

    @property
    def is_modified(self):
        """ Returns True if any object in this tree has been modified. """
        return self._modified_flag[0]

    def _set_modified(self):
        self._modified_flag[0] = True

    def _wrap_subvalue(self, value):
        """
        Given an attribute or index value, decides if it should be returned as-is
        (e.g. primitive types), wrapped in another Proxy (e.g. substructures), or 
        if it's a modifying function call and the respective flag should be set.
        """
        if isinstance(value, (int, str, float, bool, bytes)):
            return value
        elif callable(value):
            # List of functions that modify the object.
            if value.__qualname__ in ('list.append', 'list.pop', 'list.clear', 'list.extend', 'list.insert', 'list.remove', 'list.sort', 'list.reverse', 'dict.popitem', 'dict.update', 'dict.pop', 'dict.clear'):
                self._set_modified()
            return value
        else:
            return Proxy(obj=value, modified_flag=self._modified_flag)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._wrap_subvalue(getattr(self._obj, name))

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self._set_modified()
        setattr(self._obj, name, value)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._wrap_subvalue(self._obj[index])

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._set_modified()
        self._obj[index] = value
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Child:
    value: float

@dataclass
class Parent:
    """Class for keeping track of an item in inventory."""
    name: str
    children: [Child]

    def bogus_operation(self) -> float:
        return sum(child.value for child in self.children) / len(self.children)

raw_parent = Parent('parent name', [Child(value=5), Child(value=4)])
parent = Proxy(raw_parent) # Proxy here!
parent.bogus_operation()
print(parent.is_modified)
parent.children[0].value = 2
parent.children.append(Child(1))
print(parent.is_modified)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just set `unsafe_hash=True`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass

This will force the generation of a `__hash__` method similar to what you'd get with an immutable dataclass.

Note that if you do this, you need to take extra care to not accidentally use your dataclass in a context where the hash is assumed to be "safe" (i.e. static), since the hash of a mutable object is itself subject to change.  For example, making your dataclass hashable will allow you to use it as a dictionary key, but the dictionary will have undefined behavior when you modify the key since its internal hashtable will have been invalidated without its knowledge.

Comment: I was avoiding to use `unsafe_hash=True` because other than dict, I don't know what else it'll impact. Would it impact something like `[x for x in self.some_list if x.Ob_inst == obj_inst]`  if all objects where set to `unsafe_hash=True`?

Comment: I don't think it would (because that's not relying on a previously calculated hash value), but yes, there are a lot of things that might potentially be impacted.  Personally I would look a little bit harder at whether it's possible to make the dataclasses `frozen`; I don't think the duplication problem is necessarily as bad as you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works and isn't as slow as hash(str(instance)) but still slows down as the data increases (it's just within my tolerances).

Note: Slower for very small instances but much faster for very large instances.

I won't accept it since it didn't answer my specific question but in case this works for someone I'll post it here.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import os 
from pathlib import Path 
import pickle


@dataclass() 
class Investigation:

    Path: str
    PreviousHash: int = field(default=0)
    Users: list[User] = field(default_factory=list)
    Tasks: list[Task] = field(default_factory=list)
    Nodes: list[Node] = field(default_factory=list)
    Edges: list[Edge] = field(default_factory=list)

    @property
    def Name(self) -> str:
        return Path(self.Path).stem

    @property
    def Directory(self) -> str:
        return os.path.dirname(self.Path)

    def Snapshot(self):
        self.PreviousHash = hash(pickle.dumps(self))

    @property
    def HasChanges(self) -> bool:
        return hash(pickle.dumps(self)) != self.PreviousHash

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        state["PreviousHash"] = 0
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)
        self.PreviousHash = hash(pickle.dumps(self))
```